# Spring Hibernate findAll. Select only Parent class

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am having a problem. I have a oneToMany relationship. I need to have findAll methods where :
a) i can select every parent with child
b) i can select ONLY parent.

I am a little confused with lazy loading etc. How can hibernate understand what i am asking for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy Loading can be configurable, means you configure, whether you need it or not, in case of lazy loading your data will be picked when you request for it, all the data is not handPicked at FindAll at once.

- [I think this link is well explanatory](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading)